# Mutual Friend column, select a pair only once

Tags: sql

I have a table `likes`, Where ID1 likes ID2

```
ID1     ID2
1025    1101
1247    1468
1316    1304
1501    1934
1641    1468
1689    1709
1709    1689
1782    1709
1911    1247
1934    1501
```

so i am select those who like each other, that is example

```
1501 1934
1934 1501
```

But i want to select each pair only once, and i am not able to do it. Can anyone point me in the right direction ? its a part of a bigger query, but this part i am not able to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a distinct list of all reciprocated likes you can use

```
SELECT ID1,
       ID2
FROM   likes L1
WHERE  ID1 > ID2
       AND EXISTS(SELECT *
                  FROM   likes L2
                  WHERE  L1.ID1 = L2.ID2
                         AND L1.ID2 = L2.ID1)
```

Comment: Good solution. I'd also probably make an attempt to clean up the table and cause future inserts to always make ID1 < ID2 unless the direction of the "like" matters.

Comment: @TomH - Yes. There is of course no guarantee that because A likes B the reverse is also true.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i had to modifiy it a bit to fit in my solution, but this worked :)

Comment: @Pheonix - Is the relationship intended to be symmetrical or not?

Comment: @MartinSmith I am not clear what the Symmetrical Relation would mean here, but the Data is to exist like it is, as in, the LIKE is not mutual, x likes y doesn't mean y likes x.. so if and only if x and y like each other, then the two rows will exist, and thats what i wanted to select, but only once.

Comment: @Pheonix - Ah OK. My query doesn't do that. It just gets a distinct list of all likes. It doesn't ensure that the liking is mutual. I'll add a version that does that. What RDBMS?

Comment: @Martin i did that, thats what i needed to change, i was working on sqlite. my query is actually pretty big, concerning two other tables, so i thought it would be pretty out of context to put that here.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
     L1.ID1, L1.ID2
from likes L1
where exists 
     (select 1
      from likes L2
      where L1.ID1 = L2.ID2 and L1.ID2 = L2.ID1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the data:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2
  FROM likes
 WHERE ID1 < ID2
UNION
SELECT ID2 AS ID1, ID1 AS ID2
  FROM likes
 WHERE ID1 > ID2;
```

...then fix the leak by adding data integrity constraints to the table e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE likes 
(
 ID1 INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 ID2 INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 CHECK (ID1 < ID2),
 UNIQUE (ID1, ID2)
);
```

Comment: You forgot a step. Fix the application so that it doesn't error out every time that it tries to insert the IDs into the wrong columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT L1.ID1, L1.ID2 FROM Likes L1, Likes L2 
WHERE L1.ID1=L2.ID2 AND L1.ID2=L2.ID1 AND L1.ID1>L1.ID2
```